# Convert White space to 20% all of site

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I am using opencart script. i want to convert all spaces to 20%  like
 `/image/cache/data/Gallery/Need for Speed/Turbo-Car-Bed-Night-Rider-240x240.jpg` 
to

```
/image/cache/data/Gallery/Need20%for20%Speed/Turbo-Car-Bed-Night-Rider-240x240.jpg
```

I have no access to html files any solution.
any idea about `.htaccess.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: urlencode should help you with this.

Comment: Without access to HTML or PHP files this cannot be achieved. Unless You are at least able to install vQmod extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.php.net/urlencode

`urlencode($rawUrl)` converts in PHP a string in its url-encoded form.

Comment: i say i have no access to html or php any type of file, and i dont know how many files have img tag. 
**idea about .htaccess**